# HHVM 502 gateway error on high load

Tags: nginx, hhvm

I have a codebase that's running fine con HHVM.

I'm realizing some load tests with apache ab tool but when i test with 100 concurrent requests I start to get 502 gateway errors.

I generally only get two types of logs in nginx's error log:

> 2015/01/10 09:42:48 [crit] 29794#0: *302 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
>   while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.56.211, server: ,
>   request: "GET /api/v2/checkaccess HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock:", host: "instela.com"
>
> 2015/01/10 09:42:26 [error] 29794#0: *264 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.56.211, server: , request:
>   "GET /api/v2/checkaccess HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock:", host: "instela.com"

Under high load this error occurs on all load balanced backends servers, so it's not a server specific problem (I hope)

Mostly after some time HHVM returns back but many times I had to restart the daemon to bring the server back.

I am using the default configuration mostly. Here I've my configuration: http://pastie.org/9823561

Comment: It happened to me too but only after I change some configuration in Nginx or HHVM. I think that is the problem and a new restart is required. Could that be your case too?